# XML layout not loading after update android studion form Chipmunk to Dolphin

Tags: android, xml, sdk

When ever there is an error in xml file the view for the reference in Android Studio gets invisible its very hard to work without having a view reference. I have invalided the cache and restart android studio several times still not working it is only happening after updating to Dolphin from chipmunk

Answer (score 0):

Try Following :

1. You need to update Android Gradle Plugin.

   File -> Project Structure -> Project

   Then You need to update Android Gradle Plugin Version to 7.3.0 and Gradle Version to 7.4.

   And then You need to invalidate cache and restart your IDE will resolve your error.

If Still you have problem then,

2. You can Repair Your IDE By Click on File -> Repair Your IDE…

I had to do both steps to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Open your SDK Manager and install all Source Android 33 packages will solve your problem